# Drawing in 2D space using Accelerometer (gyroscope?)

Tags: android, accelerometer, physics, gyroscope

I am trying to create an application that will track movement of the device in 2D space. After doing research online, all I could find that one way to do it is integrate linear acceleration twice but the error is horrible.

Are there any solutions to this problem? I would like to be able to move my phone up, which would cause a vertical line to be drawn on the screen, to scale of how far the phone was moved. Then if I move the phone to the left, horizontal line would be drawn - effectively allowing me to draw on the screen using movements of the phone.

**Can this be done at all? If so, what direction should I take in the development? I don't know where to start...**

EDIT: More about the project:

I am trying to make an exercise app that will track the movement of the leg/arm: for example, when you are doing stomach crunches and the phone is attached with an armstrap to your ankle.

The app would track repeated movements of the leg.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the accelerometers in these phones are nowhere near what you need to implement an inertial measurement unit.  The big problem is since you are integrating twice an integration always comes with a constant integral(x,dx) = x^2/2 +c this constant is what makes this difficult.  To make things worse you get it twice, once when integrating to get velocity and once to get position.

One method of fixing this that I have seen in commercial innertial measurement units is called a zero velocity null, this is where you use some other source of data to tell it when you have stopped the motion of the device so you can zero out the velocity.  For example I saw a project put an inertial measurement unit on a shoe and it would zero the velocity whenever it detected the shoe being put on the ground which vastly improved the accuracy.  Its possible that you could use a camera or something to determine this, however I have not seen it done.  If you would like to start messing with this then you are an awesome person and I would love to hear how it turns out.

Edit: I should clarify that the constant I mention above is where the error accumulates.  If you can zero velocity null it then you periodically drop the accumulated error from your stored current velocity.  The error in position will still accumulate, however this would make it not drift when they are holding it relatively still which may make it passable for drawing.

Comment: Hey, the velocity null is a feasible solution for my problem. I am trying to make an exercise app that will track the movement of the leg as, for example, when you are doing stomach crunches and the phone is attached with an armstrap to your ankle. It sounds stupid but its of interest to me :)

Comment: Interesting, keep in mind however that the reason the shoe thing worked was that they had a switch that contacts the ground and tells the sensor exactly when it is not moving.  You may have trouble with a crunch since you are not actually putting your foot down on anything.  However with a repetitive motion like this where you reverse directions you could certainly count the number of crunches similar to how a pedometer counts steps.  You may also be able to infer your zero velocity when the acceleration stops due to the periodic nature of the motion, but this would be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I know no other way other than integrating the acceleration twice.

Moreover I think that it's not possible if you don't have knowledge about other sensors that might be in your device (for example on one of my devices I have 7 (seven) sensors related to various physical signals the device might be receiving).

Other than that remember that the sensor data is noisy and almost always *must* be pre-filtered. For example you can use geometric mean of last 10 samples. That should lower your error by providing a smoother input data to the integrating function.